# Newsletter flag set to 2 in db column?

Tags: cakephp

I want to set newsletter flag to 2 in database table, but when I do this $this->data['User']['newsletter'] = 2; It always sets to 1. Its a checkbox on registration page. Can anybody help me how to set it to 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a checkbox, you got your newsletter field to tinyint(1). which is a boolean representation of yes/no, 1/0.
SO either you only want to store a boolean value (and therefore the checkbox in the view) or you need to change your field to tinyint(2) to allow some kind of enum (more than just two definite states). But then you also need to use a select here in the view.

So what exactly are you trying to do? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I have changed tinyint(1) to int(11), but still it dosn't work.

Comment: I have two different subdomains, and I am trying when user selects newsletter on one domain, its should save 1 in newsletter field and when user selects newsletter from other subdomain the it should save 2 in the newsletter field

Comment: then you need to have some mapping in between in the controller or better model layer. without any more specifics its just guessing, though.

Comment: `$this->data` is read-only, Use `this->request->data` instead.

Comment: that is also true, of course. assuming he is using cake2.x (he didnt mention it in his question, unfortunately).